# Make a mainWindow for JAVA/SWING application

Tags: java, swing, mainwindow

When i started developping my application, I just developped Seprate JFrame frames and test them one by one. Now, i want to make a main window for my app. I read a lot, but until now, it's difficult for me to  do this in java and swing. I tried this by creating a main window as an instance of JFrame, but i got errors that shows i can't show JFrame inside another JFrame.

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame{
private JFrame frame1;
private JFrame frame2;


public MainWindow(){

frame1 = new JFrame();
frame2 = new JFrame();

setLayout(new BorderLayout());

add(frame1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(frame2,BorderLayout.NORTH);

pack(); 

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the reasons why it is generally discouraged to extend directly from top level containers like `JFrame`, they lock you into a single use.

You can't add window based components to other containers.  You will have to separate each of your current frames into a more basic container, like `JPanel`, only then can you add them to another window.

You may consider using a `CardLayout` or `JTabbedPane` or even a `JDesktopPane` or other layout manager to make your individual views available to your users depending on your needs.

See...

- [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)
- [How to Use Tabbed Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html)
- [How to Use Internal Frames](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html)
- [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

for some more ideas

Answer (score 1):

A `JFrame` is a window.

You can't put a window inside a window.

You might be looking for `JPanel`. A `JPanel` is a fairly simple container for other components (which could include more `JPanel`s). You can add `JPanel`s to a `JFrame`.

Comment: i want to add the entrie JFrame inside a panel or Parent JFrame, how i can do this?

Comment: @abdouamer As immibis said, you can't.  This is why we discourage people from extending from `JFrame` as it locks you into a implementation.  Instead, use a `JPanel` and either a `CardLayout` or `JTabedPane` (or even other layout manager) to display the separate views...

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to handle this
First of all you can't use Jframe inside of JFrame like you noticed so instead use `JPanel`

```
panel = new JPanel();

add(panel,BorderLayout.Center);
```

JPanel is an other container in which you can pack a lot of swing components.

If you want to open a new Window make anoter JFrame and make it visible. Note you can't add it to your Jframe with the method add. but you can save it in a variable and handle what you see in the other frame from the same class.
As you wanna have a mainwindow add this code into the mainwindow:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

this makes that if you close your main Frame the application will end (in the other frames you shouldn't implement this normally)